# DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.u28suggest li:first a' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute this line and getting below error

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('.u28suggest li:first a').length > 0) {
```

Error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.u28suggest li:first a' is not a valid selector.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message is telling you, that's [not a valid selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/), specifically the `:first` part, which is a jQuery-only thing, not CSS. The equivalent to what that would mean in jQuery using the DOM and CSS is:

```
// Get the first match for `.u28suggest li`
const li = document.querySelector(".u28suggest li");
// If we got one and it has at least one `a` in it...
if (li && li.querySelectorAll("a").length > 0) {
```

Or with optional chaining, since `undefined > 0` is false:

```
if (document.querySelector(".u28suggest li")?.querySelectorAll("a").length > 0) {
```

Just beware that you always need to consider what the result will be when the left-hand side evaluates to `undefined`. Again, `undefined > 0` is false here and that's what we want, but it can bite you. :-)